# Trying to return min, max, and average values of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, average, min

I'm running into difficulty trying to produce the min, max, and average values of an array.  I seem to be able to return the min value without any problem, however my attempts to produce the three values together, either separately or inside of an array, are meeting with 'undefined' as the output in the console.

Here is the code I'm running (in console):

```
function findMinMaxAvg(arr){
  var min = arr[0]; // min
  var max = arr[0]; // max
  var sum = arr[0]; // sum

  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] < min) {
      min = arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }
  return min;
  return max;
  return sum / arr.length;

  var avg = sum / arr.length;  // declaring avg variable for later arrnew variable
  var arrnew = [min, max, avg];  // output results into this new array
  return arrnew; // return all three values inside of an array
  console.log(arrnew);
}
findMinMaxAvg([1,5,10,-2]);
```

Comment: Seems you need to learn more about what the `return` keyword does. `return min;` ends your function - everything after that is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple return statements consecutively in a function. It will always exit the function on the first `return min` statement.

```
function findMinMaxAvg(arr){
  var min = arr[0]; // min
  var max = arr[0]; // max
  var sum = arr[0]; // sum

  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] < min) {
      min = arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
    }
    sum = sum + arr[i];
  }
  return [min, max, sum / arr.length]
}
```

Comment: That's it.  I did not understand this concept before.  Thank you, now I do.  No wonder.

Comment: You can then destructure the result as `var [min, max, avg] = findMinMaxAvg([1,2,3]);`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you are attempting.

```js
    var arr = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7,1, 4, 6, 5]
    var max = arr[0];
    var min = arr[0];
    var sum = arr[0]; 
    for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
   console.log('max=' +max + 'min='  +min + 'avd=' + sum/arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're 90% there!
Once you return from the function, none of the remaining code will run.
So the following statements should be **removed** and you'll get the array you expect returned!

```
  return min;
  return max;
  return sum / arr.length;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I did not understand this concept before.  Now it works.